# How to prohibit addinng attribute to a table if it exists in another

Tags: mysql, triggers, constraints, multiple-tables

I am searching for a solution for the following example:

I have a relation with Students, one for Professors and one for Books.

Students and Professors can lend books. Each book exists one ONCE.

If the Student rents Book 001, then it should be impossible to do so for the Professor.(and vice versa)

I need a constraint to prohibit that Book 001 can be added to the Professor table.

Comment: That's the wrong thinking. You don't insert the book on the professor or student table. You create a `rent` table that has `book_id, professor_id, student_id, start_date, end_date` and you create a unique constraint on this table for `book_id, start_date, end_date` and that's the correct way of designing it.

Comment: i just realized that this isn't working out because then i would need a student_id AND a professor_id everytime i rent a book.

Comment: No you don't, both of those columns can be created as nullablem as in `student_id int NULL` that tells the database that that column is not mandatory, so you can have either one. It is even possible to add a constraint check on those two columns on that table that will not allow both to be filled. something like `check ( (student_id is null and professor_id is not null) or (student_id is not null and professor_id is null))`